# In Azure Bicep how can we define multiple child with multiple parents

Tags: azure-bicep

```
@description('Optional. Name for the Event Hub cluster.')
param clusterName string

@description('Name for the Namespace to be created.')
param eh_namespaces object

/* Example
eh_namespaces = {
  prodduction1-pre: {
    sku: 'Standard'
    capacity:  4
    maximum_throughput_units: 20
  }
  production2-pre1: {
    sku: 'Standard'
    capacity:  4
    maximum_throughput_units: 20
  }
}
*/

var namespaces = [for entity in items(eh_namespaces): {
  name: entity.key
  sku: entity.value.sku
  capacity: entity.value.capacity

}]

@description('Optional. Name for the eventhub to be created.')
param eventhub_configs object = {}

/*Example
eventhub_configs = {
  audit: {
    messageRetentionInDays: 7
    partitionCount: 1
  }
  billing: {
    messageRetentionInDays: 7
    partitionCount: 1
  }
}
*/



var eventhubs =  [for event in items(eventhub_configs): {
  name: event.key
  messageRetentionInDays: event.value.messageRetentionInDays
  partitionCount: event.value.partitionCount
  eventHubNamespaceName: event.value.eventHubNamespaceName

}]

resource cluster 'Microsoft.EventHub/clusters@2021-11-01' = if (!empty(clusterName)) {
  name: clusterName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Dedicated'
    capacity: clustercapacity
  }
  properties: {}
}


resource eventHubNamespace 'Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces@2021-11-01' = [for namespace in namespaces: {
  name: namespace.name
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: namespace.sku
    tier: namespace.sku
    capacity: namespace.capacity
  }

  properties: {}
}]


resource eventHub 'Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs@2021-11-01' = [for eventhub in eventhubs : {
  name: name
  parent: eventHubNamespace
  properties: {
    messageRetentionInDays: eventhub.messageRetentionInDays
    partitionCount: eventhub.partitionCount
  }
}]
```

So for evenhub , It is showing below error:

The property "parent" expected a value of type "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces" but the provided value is of type "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces@2021-11-01[]".

Directly referencing a resource or module collection is not currently supported. Apply an array indexer to the expression

I have to create multiple namespace and eventhub in eventcluster

Comment: there is a similar question from last week, https://stackoverflow.com/q/75697220/4167200. would that help ?

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to the EventHub resource's parent property actually wants a single resource object of type `Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces`, but you are passing an array of objects.

So, you can modify the for loop by giving an index `i` which iterates over all the namespaces and event hubs arrays and create an event hub resource for each combination of namespaces and event hubs.

***I modified your script as below:***

```bash
@description('Name for the Event Hub cluster.')
param  clusterName  string
@description('Name for the Namespace.')
//param eh_namespaces object
param  location  string
@minValue(2)
@maxValue(1000)
param  skuCapacity  int = 2
param  namespaces  array = []
@description('Name for the eventhub to be created.')
param  eventhub_configs  object = {}
var  eventhubs = [for  event  in  items(eventhub_configs): {
name: event.key
messageRetentionInDays: event.value.messageRetentionInDays
partitionCount: event.value.partitionCount
eventHubNamespaceName: event.value.eventHubNamespaceName
}]
resource  cluster  'Microsoft.EventHub/clusters@2021-11-01' = if (!empty(clusterName)) {
name: clusterName
location: location
sku: {
name: 'Dedicated'
capacity: skuCapacity
}
properties: {}
}
resource  eventHubNamespace  'Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces@2021-11-01' = [for (namespace,i) in  namespaces: {
name: namespace.name
location: location
sku: {
name: 'Standard'
tier: 'Standard'
capacity: skuCapacity
}
properties: {}
}]
resource  eventHub  'Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs@2021-11-01' = [for (eventhub,i) in  eventhubs : {
name: eventhub.name
parent: eventHubNamespace[i]
properties: {
messageRetentionInDays: eventhub.messageRetentionInDays
partitionCount: eventhub.partitionCount
}
}]
```

*Deployment succeeded:*

[image]

[image]

Refer this [document](https://ochzhen.com/blog/child-resources-in-azure-bicep) by @Alex for different ways of declarations and loops.